# How can I implement a toggle on an element to change CSS with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<a id="page-width" href="#" class="button">
    <div class="icon sprite-application-text" ></div>
</a>
```

How can I make it so that when the link is clicked:

1. the class changes to `<div class="icon sprite-application-sidebar-list.png" >`
2. the object with `<section id="menu" class="grid_3"></section>` has a `width` of `0%`
3. the object with `<section id="content" class="grid_9"></section>` changes to a `class` of `"grid_12"`

and then when it is clicked again the class changes back to:

1. `<div class="icon sprite-application-text" >`
2. the object with `<section id="menu" class="grid_3"></section>` has a `width` of `23%`
3. the object with `<section id="content" class="grid_9"></section>` changes to a `class` of `"grid_9"`

I need some kind of toggle action but I am not sure how to implement this with jQuery?

Comment: `sprite-application-sidebar-list.png` is not a valid class.

Comment: Do you need some king of [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) action? http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(".icon sprite-application-text").removeClass("icon
sprite-application-text").addClass("icon
sprite-application-sidebar-list.png");

$(".icon sprite-application-sidebar-list.png").removeClass("icon
sprite-application-sidebar-list.png").addClass("icon
sprite-application-text");
if ($("#menu").width() == 0) 
{
   $("#menu").width("23%");
   $("#content").removeClass("grid-9").addClass("grid-12");
}
else
{
   $("#menu").width("0");
   $("#content").removeClass("grid-12").addClass("grid-9");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) api of jQuery.

You can easily toggle the class using that. Also, for changing the width you can define it in some css class, so that the desired width is set when you toggle it.

Comment: Not sure why this guy was downvoted. The answer seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes, perfectly valid, I would rather use a class to set the width of the element instead of using `$(element).css(...)`